# How to change icon size?

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 32bit on a dell netbook, and the icons are way too huge. I've tried clicking on the cog and logging in as "ubuntu" instead of "ubuntu 2d" but that doesn't work. what do i do?

Comment: i know you go into appearance, but that option in that menu isn't even there.

Comment: >>Press Super (Windows button) + Select Appearance -> Go to bottom you'll see Launcher Icon Size Drag it to 32.
Or you use some other tools like my unity, ubuntu tweak (google to get it).

Comment: At which icons do you refer: launcher icons, dash icons, file manager icons...?

Comment: the launcher icons on the left. I have ubuntu on two computers. one has the bar to change the icon size, and my netbook doesn't have the option to make them smaller

Answer (score 0):

You can use dconf from a terminal to write the settings.

Set it (replace ## with your preferred size):
`dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size ##`

Reset it to default:
`dconf reset /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size`

These, of course, only work if you have dconf installed, which you can do easily from the terminal:
`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Unity Tweak Tool and change the icon size from there, plus you could customize some other stuff if you feel like it(Window Snapping, Themes etc.)